# Flutter Camera Exception - CameraDevice was already closed

Tags: android, flutter, android-camera, flutter-dependencies

I have a flutter app that has a feature to record a video and save it to a file using [camera: ^0.10.0+4](https://pub.dev/packages/camera). The scenario is after the user finishes recording on VideoRecordPage, he press continue button and then the camera controller will dispose and navigates to the next page (simple FormPage which only contains some input field without open camera or preview image). The page is navigated successfully, but when the user starts typing on input field, suddenly the app crashed and show this error

```
I/Camera  (25833): startPreview
I/Camera  (25833): close
4
I/flutter (25833): last state body port: false
I/Camera  (25833): close
E/AndroidRuntime(25833): FATAL EXCEPTION: CameraBackground
E/AndroidRuntime(25833): Process: id.test.app.dev, PID: 25833
E/AndroidRuntime(25833): java.lang.IllegalStateException: CameraDevice was already closed
E/AndroidRuntime(25833):    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.checkIfCameraClosedOrInError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:2347)
E/AndroidRuntime(25833):    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSessionInternal(CameraDeviceImpl.java:684)
E/AndroidRuntime(25833):    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSession(CameraDeviceImpl.java:669)
E/AndroidRuntime(25833):    at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera$DefaultCameraDeviceWrapper.createCaptureSession(Camera.java:175)
E/AndroidRuntime(25833):    at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.createCaptureSessionWithSessionConfig(Camera.java:479)
E/AndroidRuntime(25833):    at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.createCaptureSession(Camera.java:465)
E/AndroidRuntime(25833):    at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.createCaptureSession(Camera.java:387)
E/AndroidRuntime(25833):    at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.startPreview(Camera.java:1071)
E/AndroidRuntime(25833):    at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera$1.onOpened(Camera.java:322)
E/AndroidRuntime(25833):    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$1.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:165)
E/AndroidRuntime(25833):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/AndroidRuntime(25833):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(25833):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime(25833):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(25833):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case what fixed this issue was to NOT initialize the camera controller in the initState method. If you follow the example in the camera package (camera: ^0.10.3) you will see that the camera controller is actually initialized in the onNewCameraSelected method. Basically make sure to not initialize the camera controller twice and that should fix your issue.

A few tips:

1. Make sure your camera class has "with WidgetsBindingObserver"
2. Add this line of code in your initState method: WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
3. Add this line of code in your dispose method: WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
4. Also make sure you dispose the camera controller in the dispose method: controller?.dispose();